# Using ansible to manage disk space

Tags: ansible

Simple ask: I want to delete some files if partition utilization goes over a certain percentage.

I have access to "size_total" and "size_available" via "ansible_mounts".  i.e.:

```
ansible myhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_mounts'
myhost | success >> {
"ansible_facts": {
    "ansible_mounts": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/mapper/RootVolGroup00-lv_root", 
            "fstype": "ext4", 
            "mount": "/", 
            "options": "rw", 
            "size_available": 5033046016, 
            "size_total": 8455118848
        },
```

How do I access those values, and how would I perform actions conditionally based on them using Ansible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Slava's answer definitely was on the right track, here is what I used:

```
- name: test for available disk space
  assert:
    that: 
      - not {{ item.mount == '/' and ( item.size_available < item.size_total - ( item.size_total|float * 0.8 ) ) }}
      - not {{ item.mount == '/var' and ( item.size_available < item.size_total - ( item.size_total|float * 0.8 ) ) }}
  with_items: ansible_mounts
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: disk_free

- name: free disk space
  command: "/some/command/that/fixes/it"
  when: disk_free|failed
```

The assert task simply tests for a condition, by setting ignore_errors, and registering the result of the test to a new variable we can perform a conditional task later in the play instead of just failing when the result of the assert fails.

The tests themselves could probably be written more efficiently, but at the cost of readability. So I didn't use a multiple-list loop in the example. In this case the task loops over each item in the list of mounted filesystems (an ansible-created fact, called ansible_mounts.)

By negating the test we avoid failing on file system mounts not in our list, then simple math handles the rest. The part that tripped me up was that the size_available and size_total variables were strings, so a jinja filter converts them to a float before calculating the percentage.

Comment: When I tried this, I received this error: "The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'mount'"

Comment: The answer to the 'no attribute "mount" ' problem is to use: with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}' ... however, the example appears to also break ( at least on Ans 2.2.1.0 ) when trying to use the |failed construct on a list. .. I can get the assertions working, but having trouble to get the |failed part working.

Comment: Use `when: disk_free is failed` on more recent versions of Ansible

Answer (score 6):

In my case, all I care about is the root partition. But I found when using the example from frameloss above, that I needed a negated 'or' condition, because each mount point will get tested against the assertion. If more than one mount point existed, then that meant the assertion would always fail. In my example, I'm testing for if the size_available is less than 50% of size_total directly, rather than calculate it as frameloss did.

Secondly, at least in the version of ansible I used, it was necessary to include the {{ }} around the variable in with_items. A mistake that I made that wasn't in the example above was not aligning the 'when' clause at the same indentation as the 'fail' directive. ( If that mistake is made, then the solution does not work... )

```
# This works with ansible 2.2.1.0
- hosts: api-endpoints
  become: True
  tasks:

    - name: Test disk space available
      assert:
        that:
            - item.mount != '/' or {{ item.mount == '/' and item.size_available > (item.size_total|float * 0.4) }}
      with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: disk_free

    - name: Fail when disk space needs attention
      fail:
         msg: 'Disk space needs attention.'
      when: disk_free|failed
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it but I suggest to try something like this:

```
file:
   dest: /path/to/big/file
   state: absent
   when: "{% for point in ansible_mounts %}{% if point.mount == '/' and point.size_available > (point.size_total / 100 * 85) %}true{% endif %}{% endfor %}" == "true"
```

In this example, we iterate over mount points and find "/", after that we calculate is there utilization goes over 85 percentage and prints "true" if it's true. Next, we compare that string and decide should this file be deleted.

Inspired by examples from the following blog: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/jinja2-better-ansible-playbooks-templates/

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
- name: cleanup logs, free disk space below 20%
  sudo: yes
  command: find /var -name "*.log" \( \( -size +50M -mtime +7 \) -o -mtime +30 \) -exec truncate {} --size 0 \;
  when: "item.mount == '/var' and ( item.size_available < item.size_total * 0.2 )"
  with_items: ansible_mounts
```

This will truncate any `*.log` files on the volume `/var` that are either older than 7 days and greater than 50M or older than 30 days if the free disk space falls below 20%.