# Ansible to check diskspace for mounts mentioned as variable

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and currently working on a play which will see if disk space of remote machines has reached 70% threshold. If they have reached it should throw error.

i found a good example at : [Using ansible to manage disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981907/using-ansible-to-manage-disk-space)

but at this example the mount names are hard coded. And my requirement is to pass them dynamically. So i wrote below code which seems to not work:

```
    name: test for available disk space
    assert:
    that: 
    - not {{ item.mount == '{{mountname}}' and ( item.size_available < 
    item.size_total - ( item.size_total|float * 0.7 ) ) }}
    with_items: '{{ansible_mounts}}'
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: disk_free

    name: Fail the play
    fail: msg="disk space has reached 70% threshold"
    when: disk_free|failed
```

This play works when i use:

```
item.mount == '/var/app'
```

Is there any way to enter mountname dynamically ? and can i enter multiple mount names ??

I am using ansible 2.3 on rhel

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
name: Ensure that free space on {{ mountname }} is grater than 30%
assert:
  that: mount.size_available > mount.size_total|float * 0.3
  msg: disk space has reached 70% threshold
vars:
  mount: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount','equalto',mountname) | list | first }}"
```

1. `that` is a raw Jinja2 expression, don't use curly brackets in it.
2. why do you use separate `fail` task, if `assert` can fail with a message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but it failed with below error:

    **File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 
    438, in call_test
    raise TemplateRuntimeError('no test named %r' % name)
    TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto'**

   _ fatal: [10.0.230.188]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
    }_

Comment: the default python in my system is 2.7. I did some checks seems it is a issue with jinja not from ansible as per this [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10123)

Comment: fixed the jina2 & it is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help :) for other folks in community i fixed the jinja 2 version using **sudo pip install Jinja2==2.8**

Answer (score 7):

For those who cannot use `selectattr` (like me), here is a variant of the first answer using `when` and `with_items` to select the mount point to check.

```
name: 'Ensure that free space on {{ mountname }} is grater than 30%'
assert:
  that: item.size_available > item.size_total|float * 0.3
  msg: 'disk space has reached 70% threshold'
when: item.mount == mountname
with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
```

Note: To be able to use the variable `{{ ansible_mounts }}` you need to turn `gather_facts` to `yes` that can be limited to `gather_subset=!all,hardware`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Ansible 2.5 and was able to get [Konstantin Suvorov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov) solution to work with a slight mod by adding `with_items`. Sample code below:

```
- name: Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%
  assert:
    that:
      - mount.size_available > mount.size_total|float * 0.15
    msg: Disk space has reached 85% threshold
  vars:
    mount: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount','equalto',item.mount) | list | first }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```