# How can I use Ansible to check usage of specific file system

Tags: ansible

I need to create a check very similar to that one explained here: [Ansible to check diskspace for mounts mentioned as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077630/ansible-to-check-diskspace-for-mounts-mentioned-as-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Except I need it only for specified paths (for example /var).

`{{ ansible_mounts }}` is an array of dictionaries, each containing variable `mount` that is the actual path. I need to perform the check in a loop for all items in `{{ ansible_mounts }}` only if mount is equal to some value.

Example of what I want to achieve in pseudo code:

```
foreach (mountpoint in ansible_mounts)
{
    if (mountpoint["mount"] == "/var" || mountpoint["mount"] == "/opt")
    {
        // do the check
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Jinja / Ansible? This code does the check for every single item. I need to filter it only for explicitly specified paths:

```
- name: Ensure that free space on the tested volume is greater than 15%
  assert:
    that:
      - mount.size_available > mount.size_total|float * 0.15
    msg: Disk space has reached 85% threshold
  vars:
    mount: "{{ ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount','equalto',item.mount) | list | first }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to add a `when` condition, for example

```
vars:
  my_mounts:
    - '/var/log'
    - '/var/logs/foo'

tasks:
- name: do the check
  when: item.mount in my_mounts
  with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
```