# Unable to make playbook fail if any of the disk space reached 80%

Tags: linux, ansible, diskspace

```html
- name: Display any lines that have more FS usage than 80%
  shell: df -h | awk ‘$NF { print $1, $5 } $5+0 > 80’
  register: filesystem
- debug:
    var: filesystem.stdout_lines

- fail: 
    msg: “Disk space is running low”
  when: filesystem.stdout | int > 80
```

I am expecting the playbook to fail for any lines that have more disk usage than 80%

Answer (score 1):

you need to consider:

- `filesystem.stdout_lines` is a list with multiple values, this is different to the variable in the `when` condition, which combines all those records as a single string value, that's why the comparison `| int > 80` fails, so you will need to compare one row at a time
- note that the record has the volume name and the disk, as the `print` in `awk` defines `print $1, $5`, to do the when comparison you would need to split the value, from the disk utilization you would also need to remove the percentage character and convert the value to a number to make the comparison
- you have 2 comparisons, one in the shell command with awk (`$5+0 > 80`) the result, in theory will only contains the volumes with higher disk utilization, so the `when` in the fail wouldn't be necessary

```yaml
- fail: 
    msg: “Disk space is running low in {{ item }}”
  with_items: "{{ filesystem.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: And additionally, use `gather_facts`, Ansible modules and variables to [check disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077630/) or [check diskspace for mounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44078311/6771046). ... there can be found more examples on the stack sites.