# Need custom backup filenames for file copy using Ansible

Tags: file, ansible, copy, copy-paste

I have set / array of hosts that fall in below three categories i.e

1. source_hosts (multiple servers)
2. ansible_host (single server)
3. destination_hosts. (multiple servers)

Based on our architecture the plan is to do the following Steps.

1. Verify if the files exists of source_hosts and has copy permissions for the source user. Also, verify if the "path to folder" n the destination exists and has permissions for the files to get copied. Checking if we are not "Running out of space" on the destination should also be considered.
2. If the above verification is successful the files should get copied from source_host to ansible_server
   Note: I plan to use ansible's fetch module for this http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html
3. From the ansible server the files should get copied over to the destination server's respective locations.
   Note: I plan to use ansible's copy module for this 
   http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html
4. If the file already exists on the destination server a backup must be created with a identifier say "tkt432" along with the timestamp.
   Note: Again, I am planning to use copy module for backups but i don't know how to append the identifier to the backed-up files. The module does not have any such feature of appending custom identifier to file names as of my limited knowledge.

I have the following concerns.

1. what would be the ideal ansible module to address Step 1 ?
2. How do I address the issue highlighted in Step 4 ?
3. Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Q: "`What would be the ideal ansible module to address Step 1 ?`"

A: Modules [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-manage-files-and-file-properties) and [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status). Checking "Running out of space" see [Using ansible to manage disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981907/using-ansible-to-manage-disk-space).

Q: "`How do I address the issue highlighted in Step 4 ? If the file already exists on the destination server a backup must be created with an identifier say "tkt432" along with the timestamp.`"

A: Quoting from the parameters of [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations) module

> **backup** - Create a backup file including the timestamp ...

Neither the extension nor the place of the backup files is optional. See [add optional backup_dir for the backup option #16305](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16305).

Q: "`Any other suggestions are welcomed.`"

A: Take a look at module [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html#synchronize-module).

---

Q: "`1. Is there any module to check file/folder permissions (rights) for copy-paste operation with that user id?`"

A: There are no copy-paste operations in Ansible.

Q: "`Requesting more inputs on how we can append identifiers like "tkt432" to backup filenames while using "copy" modules backup option or any other good solution.`"

A: There is no more input. Ansible does not do that.

Q: "`I feel I won't be able to use the copy module and will have to fallback to writing shell scripts for the above-mentioned issues.`"

A: Yes. Modules shell and command could help with this.

Comment: 1. Is there any module to check file/folder permissions (rights) for copy-paste operation with that user id.
2. Requesting more inputs on how we can append identifiers like "tkt432" to backup filenameswhile using "copy" modules backup option or any other good solution.  

I feel i wont be able to use the copy module and will have to fallback to writing shell scripts for the above mentioned issues.

Comment: I've answered the questions, but I feel the scope is too broad. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The chance, that a question will be answered, is bigger if the question follows [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).